# how to set classpath for java mssql connectivity

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, dbconnection, mssql-jdbc

i am writing code for java mssql connectivity in notepad++ i am not using any ide.

can anybody give me code.

how to set classpath?

jtde or jdbc driver i need code for both driver

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html, you could specify java classpath not in programmatic way pointing to the folder where the needed MSSQL driver resides

Answer (score 0):

Youn need to download the JDBC driver JAR files (and all dependencies). Then call

```
java -cp path_to_jar/jtds-1.3.1.jar;path_to_jar/jtde.jar;path_to_classes;path_to_other_jars/otherjar.jars your_main_class
```

(Alle names are sample names)

On Linux you have to use `:` as separator